# 407 authenticationrequired in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, ntlm, proxy-authentication

I work in a company where we use a proxy to access any browser website.

We would like to start API testing with JMeter, but have a problem.

Whenever I try to add an API call to petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/10, for example, and put in the proxy details in the "Advanced" section of the HTTP request + adding an HTTP authorization manager with Username + Password, it still gives me a "407 Authenticationrequired" error back.

Request headers:

[image: JMeter - request headers]

Response headers:

[image: JMeter - response headers]

In the information I have also it's that the proxy is "Ruleset Name: Authentication with Kerberos and NTLM Fallback".

This is quite a problem if I'd like to test internal APIs with any authorization on it.

Comment: _"we use a proxy to access any browser website ... Authentication with Kerberos "_ >> this kind of proxy is meant for browsers (i.e. for humans), not for services. And especially not for Java stuff. Can you get clearance to install a **proxyfier** utility on your desktop, to bridge the gap between JDumpster and your proxy? I suspect Microsoft extensions in the mix...

Comment: Hi, Company doesn't allow my to bypass the proxy unfortunately. As a simple Automation tester i don't have those rights.. I have seen i could authenticate with kerberos with Jmeter would that be a solution you think? I've been trying to authenticate with NTLM. But i always get a 407 back even with User/Pass + Domain

Comment: A "proxyfier" does not bypass the proxy -- it handles the proxy negotiation for apps that cannot do that natively. Check Wikipedia...

Comment: I have installed proxyfier and set up the proxy + proxy rule. Even with that i still get the same 407 error back. (I realised my error after research, sorry my bad.) But even with it, It still doesn't work. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Status code 407](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/407) means that **proxy** authentication required, it seems that you're using a corporate proxy to access the application under test and this proxy requires credentials.

You have 2 options of passing the proxy credentials to JMeter:

1. [Command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) like:

   ```
   jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password
   ```
2. [JMeter System properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) (you can put these lines to *system.properties* file

   ```
   http.proxyUser=username
   http.proxyPass=password
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've added the credentials in the properties file (and the proxy server on the http request) but still have a 407 status code. Could both conflict each other? I am out of ideas. :)

Comment: Have you restarted JMeter to pick the properties up?

Comment: Yes, I have. Even tried multiple times. to double check.